# Find min() value in List is not returning the right result

Tags: java, list, arraylist, min

I'm trying to find minimum value in an `ArrayList` which contains about one million rows of data. This is how far I worked it out but it is always returning wrong `min()` value in `List`. I tried `min()` method of `DoubleStream`, `Collections` and `Arrays` but they always return either zero or the wrong result. Do you have any methods for this ?

```java
List<Double> dataSubtractList = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (int r = 0; r < absoluteValueList.size(); r++){
    for(int e = 0; e < absoluteLiveDataList.size(); e++){
        dataSubtractList.add(Math.abs(absoluteLiveDataList.get(e) - absoluteValueList.get(r)));
    }
}
Comparator<Double> compare = (o1, o2) -> {
    o1 = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i = 0; i < dataSubtractList.size(); i++){
        o2 = dataSubtractList.get(i);
        if(o2 < o1) {
            o1 = o2;
        }
    }
    return 1;
};
Optional<Double> min = dataSubtractList.stream().min(compare);
double minValueInArray = min.get();
System.out.println(minValueInArray);
```

Comment: Why are you creating a comparator? And iterating over the entire array for each element? Can't you directly use min() without any arguments.

Comment: Use directly min() return always zero like I stated above.

Comment: If your `ArrayList` contains a million elements, how do you know that `min()` is returning the wrong value? And how do you know that zero is not the minimum value?

Comment: I used manual way as print out the list and saw some elements smaller than the min() and find in data there is no data could give away zero results. Anyone can help in this ?

Comment: Your Comparator's job is just to compare the two values passed to it, o1 and o2.  You're trying to make it do something outside of that simple scope (and it's not needed, as pointed out by prior comments).  I'm pointing it out as the source of your bug.

Comment: Also, I believe the bug is introduced due to the nested loop that you are running for subtracting the entire list from every value.

Comment: I have to specific pointing the compare() into the job as I desperate for the min() because no method is working or giving in the right result. I tried for loop with min = Double.Max_Value return result as zero, I tried on smaller array and it works, don’t know why ?

Comment: Show an example, just using `min()` (no Comparator) where the result is zero but the input data contains smaller values. Do you understand that your `Comparator` is not doing what a `Comparator` implementation should?

Comment: If I used min() only it would return zero in double 0.0 for Arrays, Collections, List stream() … . It always return zero. Only when I use comparator, it returned data on array but it is not the minimum value on array.

Comment: Can you give me an example for comparator in this case ? or any methods for find min() in this case. Much appreciate.

Comment: I found the glitch for the problem. you guys all is right, my big mistake while I did not check the data carefully. The min() function is running fine while it is giving in the correct result for data table. I though the input is random and can not be (i ==j) like user16320675 and Abra commented but found out it is contained in there. Thanks guys for pointing out the direction and showed me the problem is in data table, not in the code. Thanks a lot guys and have a wonderful day there.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the below piece of code instead of using Comparator.

```
Double minValue = dataSubtractList.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).min().getAsDouble();
```